# Update code to 4.1

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

This code works fine in 2.2 emulator (API 8), but it is not working in 4.1 emulator (API 
16). Any idea?

Thank you for all your answers and interest

```
   `try 
    {   
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/cofradeapps/static/hermandades.xml";
        urlHermandades = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlHermandades.openConnection();  
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        return in;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: "it is not working" isn't *nearly* enough detail about what's going on. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: You can't do networking on the UI thread on newer versions of Android, you'll need to use another thread, most likely an ASyncTask

Answer (score 0):

You can't do networking on the UI thread on newer versions of Android, you'll need to use another thread, most likely an ASyncTask.

```
private class YourClass extends AsyncTask<URL> {
     protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {

         //Do your stuff here

     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     } 

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         //When you're finished update the UI thread with your results
     }
}
```